# "trust the fact" vs. "trust to the fact"?

Tags: verbs, transitive-verbs, intransitive-verbs

I think "trust the fact" is more natural than "trust to the fact", but the search result shows that the latter is more popular. What's the difference between them? Thanks.

Yet another derived question:

What's the difference between "trust to the fact" and "trust in the fact"?

Comment: Google count statistics are inaccurate if they have quotes in the queries. Google finds 476 hits for [trust the fact](https://www.google.com/#q=%22trust+the+fact%22&hl=en&tbo=d&ei=-kXTUMjxLeeM0QGo-YHQAw&start=466&sa=N&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_qf.&bvm=bv.1355534169,d.dmQ&fp=57b747fe93862d6b&bpcl=40096503&biw=863&bih=484) (there may be more; 500 is the max), but 156 for [trust to the fact](https://www.google.com/#q=%22trust+to+the+fact%22&hl=en&tbo=d&ei=fkbTUP_zKYa_0AGS6YHoDQ&start=155&sa=N&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_qf.&bvm=bv.1355534169,d.dmQ&fp=57b747fe93862d6b&bpcl=40096503&biw=863&bih=484).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I see, these variants (with to and without it) belong to really different cases:

> Trust the fact. Trust the man.

But

> Trust something to somebody. Trust to luck.

And one more variant:

> Trust in his honesty.

Comment: Thank you, Gangnus. Then what's the difference between "trust to the fact" and "trust in the fact"?

Comment: according to http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/trust+to, "trust to the fact" is not cotrrect. "Trust in the fact" means more deep trust than "trust the fact". Look also http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/trust

Comment: "Trust to the fact" is excerpted from a formal document by Microsoft. So I hardly believe that is incorrect at first glance.

Comment: According to http://thesaurus.com/browse/trust+to?s=t, "trust to" is a synonym to "depend".

Comment: @xmllmx why would a technical document be considered as an authoritative source in terms of grammatical correctness? Neither Microsoft nor its engineers are considered experts on English language and usage, most are probably not even native English speakers. Indeed, I would be very surprised if I did _not_ find any mistakes or dubious grammatical structures in a long technical document.